# Passing variables between sed script and bash script

Tags: bash, sed

I have a shell script with up to 5 parameters. There is files with placeholders. I would like to use sed script file depending of the one variable. The problem is that when I have variables defined in the sed script - values of those variables are not put in placeholders.

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$1
B=$2
echo "Some string with _PH1_ place holders _PH2_"|sed -i -f script1.sed >> file.txt
```

one of the sed scripts file

```
#Sed script 1
s/_PH1_/${A}/g
s/_PH2_/${B}/g
```

Comment: Running `sed -i` on a pipe doesn't make any sense. `-i` can only work when `sed` is given a set of file name arguments to operate on.

Answer (score 0):

If your sed script is that short, you might as well inline it in bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$1
B=$2
#your sed commands but still part of the bash script:
sed -i -e "s/_PH1_/${A}/g" file.txt
sed -i -e "/_PH2_/${B}/g" file.txt
```

Comment: It's just example. Those sed scripts will me much longer and I need possibility to extend it.

Comment: The second command is missing its initial `s`. Also, you're reading and writing the complete file twice; you could combine the commands to `"s/_PH1_/$A/g;s/_PH2_/$B/g"` and process the file in a single pass instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the sed script as part of your bash script so the variable substitution takes place:

```
#!/bin/bash
A=$1
B=$2

cat >> script1.sed << EOF
s/_PH1_/${A}/g
s/_PH2_/${B}/g
EOF

echo "Some string with _PH1_ place holders _PH2_"|sed -i -f script1.sed >> file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to avoid keeping sed scripts definition in the bash script. It will be easier to maintain without touching production script itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -a

A="$1"
B="$2"

sedScript=$(mktemp)

printf 'sed "\n' >> "$sedScript"
cat script1.sed  >> "$sedScript"
printf '"\n'     >> "$sedScript"

echo "Some string with _PH1_ place holders _PH2_" | "$sedScript"

rm -f "$sedScript"

$ ./tst.sh foo bar
Some string with foo place holders bar
```